# I'm Indian having valid UK visa & schengen visa now I'm in UK can I travel from UK to France

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, international-travel

Is it OK to travel for France from the UK holding Indian passport & valid visa but now I'm staying in UK holding valid visa for UK also.

Comment: Welcome to Travel Stack Exchange. Unfortunately the text and the header of your question are contradictory. Do you have a visa for France or not? If so, you can travel subject to the usual rules.

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you have a valid visa for France, why do you think you wouldn't be able to travel there? Are you intending to then go back to the UK and wondering if you'll be allowed to reenter, or something like that? Please edit your question to make the situation clear.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's OK to travel to France from the UK as long as your schengen visa is valid. The visa is issued for you to be able to enter France regardless of where your flight is coming from.

Do not forget to ensure that your passport is valid for at least 3 months.

Comment: Passport validity.

Answer (score 1):

If you are legally in the UK and you have a valid visa to enter France, and your Indian passport is valid for at least three months after the date of your intended departure from the Schengen area, then you should not expect any problems related to your travel documents in traveling to France.